# Lombok - how to create custom setters and apply on different member in java

Tags: java, lombok

I would like to understand how to create a custom setter in Lombok and apply the setter on specific member. I have a class with 100 members, and for 50 of them I have a custom setter that check something X before I set the value, and another 50 that have a custom setter that check something Y before the I set the value. Can it be done?
this is a exmple , 
2 members 2 diffrent setters , 
this code is repeated  for all members in my class :

```
@JsonProperty("TAC_LAC_Start_UE1")
private Integer tacLacStartUe1;

@JsonProperty("TAC_LAC_Start_UE2")
private Integer tacLacStartUe2;

@Override
public void setTacLacStartUe1(Integer tacLacStartUe1) {
    if (Objects.equals(getTacLacStartUe1(), tacLacStartUe1)) {
        return;
    }
    this.tacLacStartUe1 = tacLacStartUe1;
    if (DocKind.ORIG == docKind) {
        ((EventDocument) prepareDirtyDocument()).setTacLacStartUe1(tacLacStartUe1);
    }
}

@Override
public Integer getTacLacStartUe2() {
    return tacLacStartUe2;
}

@Override
public void setTacLacStartUe2(Integer tacLacStartUe2) {
    if (Objects.equals(getTacLacStartUe2(), tacLacStartUe2)) {
        return;
    }
    this.tacLacStartUe2 = tacLacStartUe2;
    if (DocKind.ORIG == docKind) {
        ((EventDocument) prepareDirtyDocument()).setTacLacStartUe2(tacLacStartUe2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. "custom" in what sense? Show us a sample of the code you want to generate, and we'll tell you whether its possible.

Comment: "*I have a class with 100 members*" Lombok or not, this sounds like a bad design

Comment: I agree but , I can’t change the design .. I just want a way to simplify the getter & setter using Lombok or other 3rd party ...

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: you could try to create custom lombok annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the current version's documentation (https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter), it doesn't seem to include a way to specify custom checks for the setter (or getter). I fear you will have to manually code each and every setter.

The same applies for the [experimental @Accessor](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) feature.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Laf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/994125/laf) said, Lombok doesn't currently support this feature. However, you still can get rid of some duplicated code by extracting setters logic to the following higher-order function:

```
private void doSetTacLacStartUe(
        Integer oldValue,
        Integer newValue,
        Consumer<Integer> setter,
        BiConsumer<EventDocument, Integer> eventDocumentUpdater
) {
    if (Objects.equals(oldValue, newValue)) return;
    setter.accept(newValue);
    if (DocKind.ORIG == docKind)
        eventDocumentUpdater.accept((EventDocument) prepareDirtyDocument(), newValue);
}
```

And using it this way:

```
public void setTacLacStartUe1(Integer tacLacStartUe1) {
    doSetTacLacStartUe(getTacLacStartUe1(), tacLacStartUe1, it -> this.tacLacStartUe1 = it, EventDocument::setTacLacStartUe1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , can I create multiple custom setters and apply them on specific members of my class ?