# How to custom string setters to uppercase with Lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

I am trying to configure a default behavior for my string setters.

So far, I use the following:

```
public void setRegistration(String registration) {
    this.registration = registration.toUpperCase();
}
```

Can this be done once for all setters (at least inside a same class) using @Setter from the Lombok project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok - how to create custom setters and apply on different member in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630802/lombok-how-to-create-custom-setters-and-apply-on-different-member-in-java)

Comment: I believe it does. Thanks for the heads up @Bananon